# Java driver intermittently returns closed channel exceptions connecting to DSE cluster with SSL enabled

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver

We are using dse 6.7 and Cassandra datastax java driver 3.7.2 when we are trying to connect ssl enabled ( client-to-node) cassandra cluster from 30 microservices at a same time then we are not getting connection for few services and getting connection for remaining at that time we are able to access server using cqlsh but only with java driver few sessions are not taking connections and after some time same services takes connection properly with same configs. Can someone please guide here that is there any connection configuration or any limit on the number of concurrent connections?

Got this exception on the application side

```
Caused by: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
creating bean with name 'commonCassandra' defined in class path 
resource [com/devtest/common/configuration/cassabstract.class]:
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All 
host(s) tried for query failed (tried: 
devcassandra.yagnaiq.com/192.168.2.5:9042 
(com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: 
[devcassandra.yagnaiq.com/192.168.2.5:9042] Channel has been closed))
```

Comment: What was happening at the time?  I've seen this happen under heavy traffic.  Could be related to a lot of small requests or a few big queries.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason for the `TransportException` is that the initial connection from the Java driver times out because the nodes don't respond within the client-side timeout.

You stated that you have 30 microservices. To me this often means that each of those services have their own set of tables. If your cluster has lots of tables (over 200 tables in total across all keyspaces), the initial connection from the driver can take a long time to retrieve the schema metadata which could lead to timeouts. Now think about 30 apps (microservices) doing the same thing simultaneously and it's not too hard to see why you sometimes get `NoHostAvailableException`.

Another possibility is that the `TransportException` gets generated as a result of a failed SSL handshake. The driver tries to validate the SSL certificate by verifying the hostname. For example, if you don't specify the SAN (subject alternative name) when you generate the certificates, host verification can fail leading to the `TransportException`.

You can diagnose this problem by adding the SSL debug flag `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl` as a JVM option to your apps. Cheers!